# whats wrong with "i" here?

Tags: python, python-3.x

i want to make quad gram for letters

```
>>> from nltk.probability import FreqDist
>>> from nltk.util import ngrams
>>> from nltk.text import Text
>>> fin= open(r'C:\Users\user\Desktop\quran.txt', "r", encoding='utf-8').read()
```

i opend the folder with utf-8

```
 >>> generated_ngrams = ngrams(" " + fin, 4,pad_left=False, pad_right=True, right_pad_symbol=' ')
```

generate ngrams from fin

```
>>> for gram in generated_ngrams  :
gram
i+=1
if i > 1000:
 break
```

i make the file shorter so it is easy to handle it

```
(' ', '\ufeff', 'ب', 'ِ')
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<pyshell#6>", line 3, in <module>
i+=1
NameError: name 'i' is not defined
```

and this is the error i have

Comment: `i += 1` is essentially translated to `i = i + 1` which means you're trying to use a variable named `i` before you defined it. Define `i` _before_ you attempt to increment it.

Comment: You're trying to add to `i` but it hasn't been defined anywhere yet

Comment: for gram in generated_ngrams  :
 gram
 i = i + 1
 if i > 1000:
  break

 
('ب', 'ِ', 'س', 'ْ')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#10>", line 3, in <module>
    i = i + 1
NameError: name 'i' is not defined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure what's going on with the rest of your code, but i is never initialized before you try to increment.  It's like adding 1 to nothing, which raises an error.  Add the line:

i = 0

before your For statement.  If added after the For, you'll simply get i = 1 with every loop, since 1 is added to 0 each time.

Additionally, the gram variable isn't being used anywhere, and that too will raise an error.  Whatever the value gram is, it should be used to do something within your method.  Otherwise there's no point in iterating through generated_ngrams.

Answer (score 0):

Please use below code, It may help.

```
i = 0
for gram in generated_ngrams:
    print(gram)
    i+=1
    if i > 1000:
       break
```

Answer (score 0):

In Python, the `enumerate` function allows you loop over something with an automatic counter.

For your example, you could write your code like the following:

```
for i, gram in enumerate(generated_ngrams):
    if i > 1000:
        break
```

I would venture to say this would be the more pythonic way.